# Adding array value in a cmdlet set-transportrule

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to make a script to add a recipient in the "-From" section of a Exchange Online transport rule.

The script need to store in a variable the actuals recipients in the rule and add one more define by the user.

Here where i am:

```
#Get the rule and store in $rule variable
$rule = Get-TransportRule  -Identity xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx

#Define the new recipient to add to the rule
$newuser = "joe@contoso.com"
```

Thi is my problem:

I can get the actual recipient in the value `$rule` with `$rule.from` . The result is an array because it already have some recipients.

Command `set-transportrule` accept the variable `$rule.from` in the -from option but only take the first recipient in the array and not the others one

```
Set-TransportRule -Identity xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx -From $rule.from,$newuser
```

But it work if i use the variable with the index like this:

```
#Set the rule by re-adding the actual recipient and add $newuser
Set-TransportRule -Identity xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxc -From $rule.from[0],$rule.from[1],$newuser
```

I know I can find the number of recipients with $rule.from.count but after how can I generate the `cmdlet set-transportrule` automatically with all the index present in the variable `$rule.from` ?

EX if i have 8 recipients in the array the command should be:

```
Set-TransportRule -Identity xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxc -From $rule.from[0],$rule.from[1],$rule.from[2],$rule.from[3],$rule.from[4],$rule.from[5],$rule.from[6],$rule.from[7],$newuser
```

Or maybe a better way is possible?

Thank you!

Comment: my blind guess would be to store the array like `$arr=$rule.from` and add the `$newuser` like `$arr += $newuser`. then assign `$arr` to the -From parameter. again - blindly guessing here.

Comment: Thank you David, it seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

as you wrote in the comments my "blind guess" worked - so this is the answer:

store the current assigned addresses to a variable `$arr`

```
$arr=$rule.from
```

add the `$newuser` to the variable

```
$arr += $newuser
```

and assign `$arr` to the `-From` parameter

```
Set-TransportRule -Identity xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx -From $arr
```

to sum it up:

```
#Get the rule and store in $rule variable
$rule = Get-TransportRule  -Identity xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx

#Define the new recipient to add to the rule
$newuser = "joe@contoso.com"

#store current addresses in $arr variable
$arr=$rule.from

#append $newuser to $arr variable
$arr += $newuser

#update transport rule with $arr variable
Set-TransportRule -Identity xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx -From $arr
```